# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error when switching over to ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a text field in a tableview cell and I want to assign a custom input keyboard.  I can get the keyboard to show up, but it seems that the corresponding controller class is not connected.  When I press any button, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, or a "unrecognized selector" error.

Here is the code where I tie the tableview cell's textfield to the custom input keyboard

```
CustomNumberPadViewController *calcKeyboard = [[CustomNumberPadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomNumberPadView" bundle:nil];
calcKeyboard.equationViewController = self;
cell.variableValue.inputView = calcKeyboard.view;
```

I have action methods tied to the buttons of the calkKeyboard, and when I press the buttons, those methods are not being called.  I have even instantiated a "viewWillAppear" method which is also not being called when the keypad comes up.

I have checked the class of the numberpad and it is connected to the CustomNumberPadViewController, which contains the above mentioned methods.

Here is the code for my CustomNumberPadViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "EquationViewController.h"
@class EquationViewController;


@interface CustomNumberPadViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{
EquationViewController *equationViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) EquationViewController *equationViewController;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonDonePressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonDelPressed:(id)sender;


@end
```

And associated implementation (for brevity I've cut out the guts of the action methods and just left my debugging logs):

```
#import "CustomNumberPadViewController.h"
#import "VariableCellController.h"

@implementation CustomNumberPadViewController

@synthesize equationViewController;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIColor *backgroundPatern = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"calculatorBackground.png"]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = backgroundPatern;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

#pragma mark - Action Methods

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"61-CNPVC");    
}
-(IBAction)buttonDonePressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"117-CNPVC");
}
-(IBAction)buttonDelPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"125-CNPVC");
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to retain the CustomNumberPadViewController by either adding it with `addChildViewController` or assigning it to a property.

Try debugging it with [zombies enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode).

Comment: That did it, I tried to make it a property earlier, but must have messed up on some syntax and went on to some other ideas.  Thanks a ton.  Funny that I didn't have this problem when I wasn't using ARC.  But I think I did have a memory leak...